# PHP PDO Equivalent of INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL INSERT from a SELECT with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423384/mysql-insert-from-a-select-with-pdo)

I've historically used the `mysql_*` style of connecting to mysql via php and am finally making the trek over to PDO.  In the past I've like to use mysql's `INSERT INTO...` `SELECT...`  to insert data.  The benefit being that I could add columns to a table at a later time without completely hosing all other forms that interact with that table.  My question is quite simply. . . is there a PDO equivalent to this?

I'm not having much luck using the old syntax in a prepared statement nor do I see any examples using this format.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a PDO equivalent to INSERT and SELECT?

Comment: You can send the same SQL commands to MySQL through PDO as you used to using `mysql_query()`, including [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: My question was referencing the use of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html via PDO. This is quite a bit different than the post Jocelyn referenced. Please see response to Paul's answer below.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries don't change. You can use things like:

```
$postUser = $_POST["user_name"];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName = :postUser");
$stmt->bindParam(':postUser', $postUser);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: While this didn't directly answer the question I was asking your prompt response and confirmation that the queries don't change was helpful. I should have done a better job asking the question but the way I've historically inserted data is via http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html which does not use the VALUES piece but instead uses SELECT.  This allows for an insert only into the fields identified even if other fields are included in a table. The key to getting this to work was only using bindParam for the fields being included in my prepared statement, no more no less.

Answer (score 1):

To `INSERT`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (whatever) VALUES (:whatever)";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':whatever'=>'whatever'));
```

And to `SELECT`:

```
$sql = "SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE whatever = :whatever";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':whatever'=>'whatever'));

$row = $q->fetch();
```

For more information on prepared statements go [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).